# How to draw dashed vertical lines via CAShapeLayer in a view?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I can draw a horizontal line with this code:

```
let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()    
lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
```

I want to create a "Bar chart" which would look like this:
[image]

I have created the Bar chart, but not able to add vertical dashed lines.
**CALayer** have one method only.

Comment: Elaborate your question by posting more code and required UI design if available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To draw a vertically dashed line you could do the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 2
        lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [4,4]
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: 30, y: 50),
                                CGPoint(x: 30, y: 300)])
        lineLayer.path = path
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    }

}
```

This gives this result:

[image: vertically dashed line]